# Is it possible to not SELECT the column you wish to GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, select, group-by

Do I have to select the column I want to group by?

I want to select sales numbers and group them by the month they were in, but I don't actually want the month in my results, just the sales numbers. Can I do this? I cant seem to get it to work:

```
SELECT Line_Item_Total 
FROM CUSTOMER 
GROUP BY MONTH(Actual_Setup_Date), YEAR(Actual_Setup_Date)
```

I should add this is for a delimited data chart in Filemaker.

Comment: You should somehow aggregate `Line_Item_Total `.

Comment: Not sure I'm following. Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it?

Comment: Basically, I am building a chart in Filemaker, I just need the hard data sales numbers for each month. I will add in some WHERE statements to get what I need, but I cant get even get this far. Was just wondering if my issues were because I wasnt selecting the date field but trying to group by it.

Comment: I am trying to get the sum of the Line_Item_Total field for each month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an aggregation function on the rest of the columns, that is all:

```
SELECT SUM(Line_Item_Total )
FROM CUSTOMER 
GROUP BY MONTH(Actual_Setup_Date), YEAR(Actual_Setup_Date)
```

You do not need to include the expressions in the `group by` in the `select`.

Comment: Thank you - I think I was missing the sum without even thinking that I wanted the Sum. I guess I assumed by grouping it, it would sum it :)

Comment: I still cant get it to work though, I think its my date field. Its in USA format of 05/31/2015 - could that be an issue?

Comment: @MikeDavis . . . That is not an issue if the date is stored in the database properly, using native date/time formats.  Storing a date as a string is to be highly discouraged.  If you have to, then store it using the ISO standard format of YYYY-MM-DD.